# How do I correctly convert strings to ints and input them into a list?

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that asks the user for numbers for as long as he inputs positive values.
Here's the code that I currently have written, but I've not come to complete understanding with the function of  and .Parse methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Chapter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int input;
            
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            Console.WriteLine("Input number: ");
            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            numbers.Add(input);

            while (input >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input number: ");
                input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int val = Int32.Parse(input);
                numbers.Add(val);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("the numbers you have input are");
            foreach (int number in numbers)
            {
                Console.Write(number + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int val = Int32.Parse(input);` You are trying to parse an `int` to an `int`, here. That won't fly.

Comment: both Convert.ToInt32() and Int32.Parse() does convert string to int value but you trying to convert int (input variable) to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to use the `Int32.TryParse` method. This allows you to validate the input and handle it accordingly as well as converting to an int.

See the below example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int input;
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input number: ");
            while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value entered was not a number, try again.");
                Console.WriteLine("Input number: ");
            }

            if (input >= 0)
                numbers.Add(input);
        }
        while (input >= 0);
        Console.WriteLine("the numbers you have input are");
        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write(number + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with *user input*, I'd rather use `int.TryParse` (what if user provides `"bla-bla-bla"`?).
I aslo suggest using *infinite loop*: keep asking user until (s)he puts negative value (in which case
we `break` the loop):

```
   List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

   // keep reading user input  
   while (true) {
     Console.WriteLine("Input number: ");

     // We try parsing (i.e. converting) user input - Console.ReadLine()
     // into integer value - number
     if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number))  
       // if parsing fails, say, user put "aha!", we let user know it 
       Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer number, please, try again");
     else if (number < 0)
       // if number is negative stop asking user
       break;
     else    
       // non-negative numbers are added into the list  
       numbers.Add(number);
   }

   Console.WriteLine("the numbers you have input are");

   // You can print the list in one go:
   Console.Write(string.Join(" ", numbers));
```

Parseing detail:

```
   int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int number)
```

`int.TryParse` takes user input `Console.ReadLine()` as an argument and returns `true` or `false` whether parsing succeeds or not. In case parsing succeeds, `number` contains parsed value.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Convert.ToInt32(string)` or `Int32.Parse(string)` do nearly the same thing. The difference is that `Convert.ToInt32` will return `0` if the input is `null` and `Int32.Parse` will throw an exception.

If you were to look at the implementation you will find that `Convert.ToInt32` calls `Int32.Parse`.

Anothing thing to note is that the `Convert` class allows you to convert a much wider range of types to intergers. The `Int32.Parse` method only accepts strings.

The issue with your code is in this block:

```
input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int val = Int32.Parse(input);
```

The input value has already been converted and is now an integer. This cannot be parsed (and doesn't have to be).